# MySQL Show Results in line in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I wan't to select data from database using mysql query and then save each value in variable so I will echo out latter
Here is my PHP

```
  $sql = "SELECT username FROM users Order by ID Desc Limit 0,5"; 
 $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
  $a = $row['0'];
  $b = $row['0'];
  $c = $row['0'];
  }
echo $a ."<br>" .$b ."<br>" .$c."<br>" ;
```

It show results like this same names

```
John
john
john
```

I want to show it like this

```
John
Richerd
Tony
```

Comment: It's showing John, John, John, because you keep updating your variable with every iteration, thus leaving you with only John..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your variables with each iteration leaving you with  the name from the last iteration only. You should capture the names in an array and then display them when you have captured all of them. `implode()` makes adding `<br>` tags easy.

```
$users = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $users[] = $row['0'];
}
echo implode('<br>', $users) . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$row` variable will be updated only once per iteration.

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users Order by ID Desc Limit 0,5"; 
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $row['0']."<br>";
}
```

Note that this variant adds an additional `<br>` tag at the end. Thus, as proposed in the other answers, the [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/implode) function would be a better way to go.

Comment: +1 This answer is just as effective and uses less code.